# Java fixed element's position

Tags: java

I need to build BlackJack game as an study project.

I want build it with SWING GUI. What I need it just divide the screen in 2 parts, and then to be able insert elements (in my case it's extended JButton with signed ImageIcon) using absolute (x, y) position relative to specified part.

Something like that:

[image]

I came from developing under Android, where you can work with elements in very simple way, and I feel lost in SWING. There aren't AbsoluteLayout or something like that?

Here is one example of my several attempts to this:

```
    public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JFrame  jFrame = new JFrame("Blackjack");
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container pane = jFrame.getContentPane();
    Insets insets = pane.getInsets();
    
    URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("10_of_clubs.png");
    
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    try {
        bi = ImageIO.read(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    Image resizedImage = bi.getScaledInstance(128, 186, 0);
    
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);
    
    ImageButton imgButton = new ImageButton(icon);
    imgButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(128, 186));

    ImageButton imgButton2 = new ImageButton(icon);
    imgButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(128, 186));
    
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    
    JPanel headPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel headPanel2 = new JPanel();
    
    GridBagConstraints cns = new GridBagConstraints();
    cns.gridx = 0;
    cns.gridy = 0;
    cns.weightx = 0.5;
    cns.weighty = 0.2;
    cns.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    cns.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;        
    headPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    
    headPanel.add(imgButton, cns);
    
    GridBagConstraints cns2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    cns2.gridx = 0;
    cns2.gridy = 0;
    cns2.weightx = 0.5;
    cns2.weighty = 0.2;
    cns2.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    cns2.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;        
    headPanel2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    
    headPanel2.add(imgButton2, cns2);
           
    pane.add(headPanel);
    pane.add(headPanel2);
    

    jFrame.setSize(800, 600);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
```

That what I get:

[image]

Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

if you want absolute layout, please take a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html
in general to read about layouts in java you can take a look at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html
here is all java swing components: visual guide:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

I think you can use JSplitPane (http://algo.math.ntua.gr/~symvonis/other-material/java_material/JavaTutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) to create vertical separation

Answer (score 0):

Since you have overlapping elements you can:

1. Use your existing JButtons with images inside a [JLayeredPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html). Put your cards on different layers for a clean rendering. Set the position of your Cards absolute with 'setBounds()'
2. Draw your cards with absolute position yourself using a Canvas. If you take this approach, you will also have to do your Click handling yourself (check if a click is inside a card.)